# The following code only produces an output true. How to debug it?

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code to generate prime numbers. However, instead of generating prime number, it generates the entire list on numbers from 2 to the number that is fed into the function. How to resolve this?

```js
var i = 2;
var primeCheck = function(number){
    while(i<number){
        if(number%i===0)
        {
           break;
        }
    i++;
    }
if (i===number)
{
  return true;
}
};

var primeGen = function(limit){
    for(k=2; k<=limit; k++)
    {
        if(primeCheck(k)){
            console.log(k);
        }
    }
};
primeGen(10);
```

**EDIT**: I realized that I was quite unclear with my question. So I updated it. My guess is that the "return true" is causing this nuisance. Therefore I had asked my previous question based on that.

Comment: btw you need i<=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)). Else you'll fail on primes squared like 49. And consider writing `i * i <= number` as that's cheaper.

Comment: Well, `undefined` is not a prime, so your function doesn't return `true`, so the `alert` is not being alerted... **Did you mean to pass a number into `if(primeCheck())`...?!**

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, will keep that in mind

Comment: @deceze Actually, I want to do exactly that. However, if I put in the parameter "number" which I used for my function declaration, it outputs an error saying that "number is undefined"

Comment: You want to call `primeCheck` without arguments and expect it to return `true`? Why? Why is "no number" a prime?

Comment: I know I cannot call it without and argument, but then, how do I use it within an if statement? For example:
`if(primeCheck(number))
{
     condition
}`
However, I want that number to be user defined.

Comment: @Bathsheba : If I remove the `Math.sqrt()` function, that ought to resolve the problem.

Comment: I'm confused what you're confused about. You're calling `primeCheck(11)` and it returns `true`, as evidenced by the console output. That's how you call functions correctly (however the return value in this case is rather wasted, since you're not doing anything with it). In your previous `if` statement, you're not passing any number, which makes the entire function call nonsensical. If you want to display an alert if and when a number if prime, you need to pass that number which you want to check into the function: `if (isPrime(11)) alert('prime')`

Comment: @deceze :I am updating the code. Actually, I realize I should have put down the entire code to avoid confusion. I will put up the code shortly.

Comment: @deceze : Updated it

Comment: Just follow the execution step by step with pen and paper. It makes no sense. `i` is `2` at first, so is `number`. `i < number` is `false`, so it goes straight to `i === number`, which is `true`. Next time `number` is `3`, `number % i` is not true, `i` is incremented to `3`, and you're back to the same behaviour as before. Then `i` **stays** `3`, and you're repeating the same behaviour over and over.

Comment: @deceze: thanks for pointing that out. I wonder how stupid I was to miss something so fundamental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return something you have to `return` instead of `alert; break`. I would consider refactoring this though. First of all, you should never have a function that performs such a simple task rely on an outside variable. Keep it modular.

```
function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return num > 1
}
```

This will return true if the number is prime and false otherwise. This is useful because you now have the flexibility to do multiple things with it. If you want to return true or false, it does that. If you want to output something else like "prime" or "not prime" it's very easy to wrap further.

```
function isPrimeText(num) {
  return isPrime(num) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime"
}
```

Comment: It will be much more efficient if you replace the stopping condition with `i * i <= num`, and marginally better if you replace `i++` with `i += 2`.

Comment: Why did you use `return num>1` ?

Comment: Because at that point in the loop, the number can either be {-infinity ... 1} (Not prime) or 2 or any other prime number. This is the simplest way to account for both. You return true if the number is greater than 1, excluding all potential non-primes that made it past the loop.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. Actually I am quite new to programming so I do not know how to optimize my code.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree there are many optimizations that could be made for runtime but that seems to be beyond the scope of this problem.

Comment: No, I'd fail any candidate who didn't see the merit of only running up to the square root.

Comment: I don't think this person is here to apply for a job. Also some interviewers would penalize for pre-optimizing so your personal preference is not really a useful metric for helping someone learn to code. Again, way beyond the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `primeCheck(11)` in your condition where you want to put alert
There is some error in your logic, when I try with primeCheck(12) it does not gives intended result.

```js
var i = 2;
var primeCheck = function(number){
    while(i<Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number))){
        if(number%i===0)
        {
           alert("Not a prime");
           break;
        }
    i++;
    }
   if (i===Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)))
   {
     return true;
   }
};

//now check for prime or not prime
if(primeCheck(11))
{
    alert("prime");
}

if(!primeCheck(12))
{
    alert("not prime");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition that returns the alert runs with primecheck() without parameters. Correct it to:

if (primeCheck(11)) {

alert("prime");

}

Also, remove the last line with the call to primeCheck(11).